# Query git index for chmod values on Windows

Tags: windows, git, executable, chmod

Is there any way to test if a file is marked as executable from Windows?

I've found that when I create shell scripts, I need to run `git update-index --chmod=+x myfile.sh` to set the executable flag ([related docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---chmod-x)).  I'd like to create a pre-commit hook to check for this flag in the git index, and warn me if it's not present.  However, there doesn't seem to be a `git query-index` type command to allow me to check if the file's been granted executable permissions.
Git Bash seems to be able to see this, as it shows executable files in green, but I'm not sure how it achieves this.

Comment: Bash won't look at the index. You could see if a file is executable by using `test -x somefile`. https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to create a pre-commit hook to check for [executable permission] in the git index, and warn me if it's not present. However, there doesn't seem to be a `git query-index` type command to allow me to check if the file's been granted executable permissions.

To read out the information from Git's index, use `git ls-files --stage`.  With no arguments, this dumps out the entire index content; with a pathspec (file or directory name, glob expression, etc.), it dumps out those names that match the pathspec.

The first entry on each line is the *mode*.  There are only two valid "file" modes these days,<sup>1</sup> namely `100644` and `100755`, so each line that begins with one of these represents a file that will go into the next commit.  The `100644` files are the ones that are `chmod=-x` and the `100755` files are the ones that are `chmod=+x`.  Anything that is not one of these two modes is not an ordinary file.

Note that this is only relevant to Git's index settings.  Windows file systems use a different security model, which is not very accommodating to Git's execute/no-execute concept.  See [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1279277/941003) and its comment for some links to Cygwin-related discussions about how Cygwin implement their `chmod`.

---

<sup>1</sup>In very early Git versions, which are no longer in use, more `100xxx` modes were allowed; the `xxx` part was a standard Unix `chmod` permission.  This was discovered to be a mistake, so now the mode is always either `rw-r--r--` (644) or `rwxr-xr-x` (755).  Any entries that have some other leading bits denote something else: `120000` is a symbolic link, and `160000` is a gitlink.  The mode `040000` is reserved for tree objects, but the index doesn't hold such objects.  These mode bits mirror the inode format mode bits in Linux, which is why there are these odd gaps.

Comment: That's a great answer - thank you.  I've knocked up a rough PS function to give a boolean test using the above logic (it doesn't cover the more "not an ordinary file" scenarios / I've just gone for simplicity).  https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/2706dc9e2e965c5d88c43f462465d327